# Is Venn diagram the best approach to represent specific operations on sets?

Tags: r, data-visualization, python

I would like to produce a visualization representing all these propositions:

[image]

The only idea which came to mind was a Venn diagram. Is it the proper approach? If yes which package (R or Python) would you recommend?

If it's not, which approach would you recommend?

Comment: Although people have created Venn diagrams to represent relationships among more than three sets, they rapidly get extremely complicated.  Have you considered just tabulating the possibilities?  There are $2^9=512$, but they probably simplify into groups.

Comment: [Wikipedia article for higher numbers of sets here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets) And [SCNR](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/2406/2853).

Answer (score 2):

A Venn diagram is one possibility.

The problem is that you can't create one without making statements that are not in your list. For instance, your list of statements doesn't tell us anything about $\text{ES}\cap\text{ANN}$, but if you want to include both sets in a Venn diagram, you will need to decide whether you visualize one inside the other, or the two overlapping, or the two disjoint. If you are good with following up all the possible combinations your nine (if I counted correctly) sets entail and actually making (visual) statements about them, then do go ahead.

Alternatively, you may want to keep your list in the format it currently is in. Or separate it out into smaller Venn diagrams.

I am unaware of any software that will transform a list of statements such as yours into a Venn diagram. It does seem like a rather complex task.

Comment: I doubt that trying to represent complex relationships among nine sets can be effectively accomplished with Venn diagrams--but I would admire any reasonable attempt to do so! These statements can be interpreted as logical propositions.  Software that draws truth tables for sets of propositions therefore could handle this without difficulty.  Software that algebraically resolves systems of propositions will do it, too.  (I'm pretty sure *Mathematica* can do this.)

Comment: The list tells you that ES $\cap$ ANN = 0, because ES $\cap$ ML = 0 and ANN $\subset$ ML

Comment: Ah, I see. Good luck digging through all the possible combinations ;-) (You can use MathJaX, which is LaTeX-like, by enclosing LaTeX code within single or double dollar signs.)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand there is no algorithm to solve this problem yet, I used pen and paper to find a solution. Here it is:
[image]

Comment: How confident are you that it's correct?  For instance, it seems to me that in this configuration you have drawn, $BDA\cap ES\cap DL = \emptyset$, contradicting one of your requirements.  It's clearly the case that $DV\cap ES \cap DL \cap BDA=\emptyset$, contradicting another. Indeed, it looks like *nothing* will satisfy all your requirements.  Maybe you should just find a way to visualize the empty set.  Here's one:

Comment: You're totally right, some of my requirements are false, my mistake. However, the drawing seems to represent properly what I have in mind. I will amend the propositions, thank you.